# List of tags in HTML - plain comma separated list or ul with some css?

Tags: text, html-lists

On a website I'm creating I'm displaying some tags for each news entry.

Now there are two ways to display the tags: simply using a string `tag1, tag2, tag3` or putting them in a list `<ul><li>tag1</li><li>tag2</li><li>tag3</li></ul>`.

Of course I would style this list so it looks exactly like the plain string: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/YKFH5/

My question is now: Which of these methods would you use and why? From what I know the necessary CSS for the list method is widely supported and in older browsers the only thing missing would be the commas.

Comment: Why in the world would you go to such great lengths to mimic the behavior of plain text?!?!?!?

Comment: One advantage would be easily being able to modify it using JavaScript. I don't need that right now though. My main thought was that it's a list of items so from a semantic point of view using a list would be more correct.

Comment: Good point. I'd stick to the `<li>`, as you could have greater control over the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you just want to list the items, there's nothing wrong with your first method, just listing the text out. The reason to go the other route would be if you want to style each item, or for some other reason separate them for clicking, hovering, etc...

**Demo with hover effect:** http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/YKFH5/3/

Comment: Absolutely 100% yes! In my code, I am only implementing a color change, which can be done with CSS, but you might want to play a sound on hover, or perform some other JS. - something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/YKFH5/5/

Comment: Don't forget that HTML mark-up has a lot of benefits beyond what can be seen

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the UL option, as that seems more semantic.  Of course, if you don't ever plan on doing anything with those tags rather than just list them, it doesn't really matter either way.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to make a list, in order to format it as if it were a plain string, why not just used a plain string? You can dynamically format that string anywhere you like, very easily, with no css required.